# How to calculate total supply for validator rewards

Tags: validator, staking, rewards, supply

in the solana docs it is mentioned that
`issuance = (total supply * inflation)/target_epochs_per_year` - (where target_epochs_per_year = 182.5)
Now, I am unable to understand do we consider the total supply of SOL for this formula closer to start of the epoch or to the end of it (the two values are different since 50% tx fees get burned during the poch and total supply decreases).
Could someone please confirm ? thanks. Also,let me know if this is not the correct channel to post it in